# How to batch delete files in several folders on Nexus 9

Tags: usb-connection-mode, file-management, nexus-9

On a Nexus 9, using bookshelf with fbreader, I have copied lots of folders from Calibre on a PC to Books folder. Each folder contains a `metadata.opf` file which the bookshelf for some reason considers and shows as a separate book, but when opened it shows nothing.

So I want to delete all these `metadata.opf` files, but going in succession to all these folders and deleting them one by one would take ages.

If I could get into the Books folder from the command prompt on the pc I could issue a single shell command to do what I want.

But I don't know how to do it. Windows Explorer shows portable device Nexus 9 connected, I can get inside from Windows Explorer, I can search for all `metadata.opf` files in Windows Explorer, and it gives me a long list of these files, but I cannot delete them all - I can delete them one by one but when I select them all and choose delete, a window pops up telling

```
An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting the file. If you continue to
receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this
problem.

Error 0x80004002: No such interface supported
```

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried using a terminal emulator and just do `for f in $(find . | grep 'metadata.opf'); do rm $f; done`?

Comment: @aureljared Well there are several ways to do it on the Android side - finally I easily did it with Simple Explorer, it was just that I was working from pc and wanted to do it right away. So strictly speaking it is a Windows question rather than an Android question...